# Using onClick to call the same function works for one thing and not another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I'm creating an application where a user can search for a device with a search bar, or look through a nested menu. When the user finds the device they want, they click on the green plus to add it to their "bag". For some reason the `addDevice` function I've written only works for the search function, and not when it's called in the menu. It seems to partially work, but not correctly. Does anyone know what in my code could be causing this? Please see the images below for more details.

I'm also making two different API calls, one for the search bar (called in its own function) and one for the menu (called in `componentDidMount`). Could this possibly be what's causing the error?

I won't include every line of code because it's a lot, but please let me know if you'd like to see anything else.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    devices: [],
    bag: [],
    objectKeys: null,
    tempKeys: []
  };
```

this is the function that gets called by the onClick's

```
addDevice = (e, deviceTitle) => {
    const array = Array.from(this.state.bag || []);
    if (array.indexOf(deviceTitle) === -1) {
      array.push(deviceTitle);
    } else {
      return;
    }
    localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(array));
    this.setState({
      bag: array
    });
  };
```

This is the function that doesn't seem to work when addDevice is called

```
makeMenuLayer = layer => {
    const { objectKeys } = this.state;
    if (layer == null) {
      return null;
    }
    const layerKeys = Object.entries(layer).map(([key, value]) => {
{/*If value has children, display an arrow, if not, do nothing*/}      
var arrow = Object.keys(value).length ? (
        <i
          className="fas fa-angle-right"
          style={{ cursor: "pointer", color: "gray" }}
        />
      ) : (
        ""
      );
{/*If value has no children, display an plus sign, if not, do nothing*/}
      var plus =
        Object.keys(value).length === 0 ? (
          <i
            className="fas fa-plus"
            style={{ cursor: "pointer", color: "green" }}
            onClick={e => this.addDevice(e, this.value)}
          />
        ) : (
          ""
        );
      return (
        <ul key={key}>
          <div onClick={() => this.handleShowMore(key)}>
            {key} {arrow} {plus}
          </div>

          {objectKeys[key] && this.makeMenuLayer(value)}
        </ul>
      );
    });
    return <div>{layerKeys}</div>;
  };
```

this is where the addDevice that does work gets called

```
render () {
   return(
            <div className="search-results">
              {(this.state.devices || []).map(device => (
                <a key={device.title}>
                  <li>
                    {device.title}{" "}
                    <i
                      className="fas fa-plus plus input"
                      style={{ cursor: "pointer", color: "green" }}
                      onClick={e => this.addDevice(e, device.title)}
                    />
                  </li>
                </a>
              ))}
            </div>
)}
```

This is what it looks like when devices are added from the search (works fine)
[image]

This is what happens when I try to add "Necktie" from the menu. It doesn't let me add anything else after that

[image]

Comment: It might be easier to answer if you used something like jsfiddle to upload part of the code causing the problem, allowing others to replicate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line `onClick={e => this.addDevice(e, this.value)}` 
The value of `this` points to the class itself. Thus, `this.value` is `undefined`, It's not not allowing you to add anything more because `undefined` is already in the array and `undefined === undefined` is actually true.
To fix this, you need to pass the correct value of the device title.

Comment: Of course! I don't know how I missed that, I meant to put ```key``` instead of ```this.value```. Thanks so much!!!